# Como percorrer os elementos irmãos com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O que eu quero fazer é com que ao passar o mouse sobre alguma estrela, todas as anteriores inclusive ela ficasse com uma classe "selecionada", tentei usar o siblings juntamente com o each e quase cheguei no resultado onde queria.

O resultado que quero chegar é mais ou menos assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**JQUERY**

```
$('.estrela').on({
    'mouseenter': function () {
        $(this).siblings().each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
        });
    }, 'mouseleave': function () {
        $(this).removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <h5>1 - Quantas estrelas você recomenda?</h5>
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?>
     <a href="#" class="estrela fa fa-star-o" data-estrelas="<?= $i; ?>"></a>
    <?php endfor; ?>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa o `event.target` para saberes qual o elemento atual, e itera sempre a coleção. Depois com um `return false;` fazes o loop parar.

Sugestão:

```js
var estrelas = $('.estrela');
estrelas.on({
  'mouseenter': function(e) {
    estrelas.each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
      if (this === e.target) return false;
    });
  },
  'mouseleave': function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ECC202;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="estrela fa fa-star-o"></a>
<a href="#" class="estrela fa fa-star-o"></a>
<a href="#" class="estrela fa fa-star-o"></a>
<a href="#" class="estrela fa fa-star-o"></a>
<a href="#" class="estrela fa fa-star-o"></a>
```

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, era exatamente isso que eu queria!